# Apache giving 403 error when accessing root; viewing .html files is working

Tags: apache, directory, root

I've set up a website in Apache using a .conf file. The contents of which are:

```
Alias /clear /media/59a6e711-e77c-42f0-917f-1d022670e89d/clear
MaxRequestLen 2147483648
FcgidMaxRequestLen 2147483648
FcgidIOTimeout 300
<Directory /media/59a6e711-e77c-42f0-917f-1d022670e89d/clear>
   Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

The problem is, I can access, say, http://domain.com/site/index.html, but when I try accessing http://domain.com/site/, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

There are two other sites with similar .conf files that work perfectly on this server, why can't this one just work when going to the root?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may be lacking a `.htaccess` file in the root directory. If this is the case, you will need to create one with, at a minimum, the content:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

This will allow "/" to map to the correct location.

Comment: Doing that gives me a 403 Forbidden if I try to access anything, including .html files...